# Extracting values from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider these lists :

```
soln = Table[i, {i, -17, 17}]; 
coordinates = Catenate[Table[{x, y}, {y, -2, 2}, {x, -3, 3}]];
solnlist = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2} &, {coordinates, Chop[soln]}];
```

`solnlist`, in my case, is a list of solution placed against coordinates. I want to extract the values given the coordinates. For this purpose, I made a function:

```
u[x_, y_] := Catch[
    Do[
        sol = solnlist[[o]]; If[sol[[1]] == x && sol[[2]] == y, Break[]],
        {o,Length[solnlist]}
    ];
    Throw[sol[[3]]]
];
```

This function does the work, that is, it gives me the value at a point $(x,y)$ from the solnlist. However, when the length of solnlist is large, it is a bit slow process. I have a bigger code where I am using such a function inside a loop. The loop takes a lot of time to execute. Is there any faster way to perform such an extraction process?

Comment: `Cases[solnlist, {-1, 2, f_} :> f]` but you could also do `ClearAll[solnlist]; MapThread[(solnlist[#1[[1]], #1[[2]]] = #2) &, {coordinates, Chop[soln]}];
solnlist[-1, 2]`

Comment: Could use `Nearest[]`: `nf = Nearest[Thread[coordinates -> soln]]; u[x_, y_] := First[nf[{x, y}]]`. `Interpolation[]` is also a possibility.

Comment: Thank you all. These functions work much faster than mine.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a perfect job for [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association):

```
assoc = AssociationThread[coordinates, soln];
```

Then, to find the value associated with a single coordinate:

```
assoc[{1, 2}]
```

> 15

To find the values associated with multiple coordinates:

```
Lookup[assoc, {{1,2}, {-1,2}}]
```

> {15, 13}